# How to output "data1.dat" file using "iswap" subroutine using the following code?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
 subroutine iswap (file, b)
  integer  b
  open(1,file = "file",status='unknown',form="unformatted")
  write (1) b
  close(1)
  end

  program callex                                                                                                                                                                         
  open(22, file = 'data1.dat')
  call iswap(file,2)
  close(22)
  stop                                                                                                                                                                                   
  end
```

Output: empty dat1.dat file

I'm completely new to Fortran. I'm trying to write the code that produces an output file "dat1.dat" containing the value of b, i.e 2, by using the "iswap" subroutine, but I'm getting an empty file. Could you please tell me the mistake I made in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. I also suggest reading [ask]. Please do not fill the tag field with multiple Fortran standard versions like [tag:fortran95] and [tag:fortran77]. The [tag:fortran] tag is entirely sufficient if you do not want to specify a specific standard revision (rarely needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

```
open(1,file = "file",status='unknown',form="unformatted")
```

you are opening (creating if does not exiat) creating a file called "file"

and by

```
write (1) b
```

you write the value of `b` to this file.

The file "data1.dat" is opened under unit 22 so you have to write to that unit if you want to write to this file.

```
write (22) b
```

There is no reason to open and close another file called "file" in your subroutine.

**It is also very important to use `implicit none`.** Otherwise you have will be surprised by having undeclared stuff like the `file` variable you use in `call iswap(file,2)`.

You can pass the unit number to your subroutine

```
  subroutine iswap (unit, b)
  implicit none
  integer  unit, b
  
  write (unit) b

  end

  program callex    
  implicit none                                                                                                                                                                     
  open(22, file = 'data1.dat')
  call iswap(22,2)
  close(22)
                                                                                                                                                                                    
  end
```

There is no reason for the `stop` statement before the `end`. It is useless and may indoce some surprising messages like the signalling FPE exceptions.

Finally, you should to learn how to put your subroutines into a module as soon as possible. I strongly suggest to avoid external subroutines if at all possible. Also use some consistent indentation (spaces at the start of the lines) so that the structure is better visible.

```
module subs
  implicit none

contains

  subroutine iswap (unit, b)
    integer, intent(in) ::  unit, b
    write(unit) b
  end subroutine
end module

program callex   
  use subs
 
  implicit none
                                                                                                                                                               
  open(22, file = 'data1.dat')
  call iswap(22, 2)
  close(22)                                                                                                                                                                       
end program
```

It is also quite useless to use `status="unknown"`. If you want to specify status, choose something specific `"old"`, `"new"`, `"replace"`, otherwise just leave it out. There are many other specifiers in the `open` statement that are worth learning, like `action` (read/write) and others that control other modes for binary files. This is not a place to show them, they are explained in various manuals, tutorials and textbooks.

Comment: Thank you, Vladimir. :)